# create style class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

i want to crate style class in java script tags

and class will be like this

```
     #file-ok {
        background-image: url(+   json.get('filename')   +);
     }
```

actually json.get('filename') will be name of file for background and will return from php file.

is this possible...?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your image filename and then set it as the background of the `#file-ok` element when the Ajax request ends:

```
$(function () {
  $.get("file.php", function(data){
    $('#file-ok').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + data.filename + ')');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to apply an inline style, but this is no good if you need to apply this to multiple elements then look at using setProperty() on a CSSRule.

You can find a great write up here - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html